# Block "edit" after filling a group of custom fields?

Tags: wordpress, custom-fields, roles, admin

Custom fields can be assigned to Contacts, Campaigns, Activities, etc. and these custom fields can be filled with information and edited. **In our organization we believe it is important to be able to BLOCK the editing of some fields after filling out at least "once"**. This is for modification security.

We know that some roles can solve this, however, in our situation, some users should be able to edit some custom fields (to modify the data registered in them) but should not edit other custom fields after a single registration.

Is this possible?
[image]